# JMeter| SAP Fiori | Load Test | Login Issue

Tags: jmeter, url-parameters, sap-fiori

I want to perform a load test on Fiori Apps but I am not able to login into the Fiori Portal when passing credentials in URL. Please suggest a way.

Example:

```
abc.com/sap/bc/ui2/flp?sap-client=00&sap-language=EN&sap-user=dwdw&sap-password=wdwdw
```

Note: I am using JMeter for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am successfully able to perform the login activity after performing some correlation between dynamic parameters of the Open Fiori Launchpad Page and Login page.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you're not certain regarding how to properly build a request the easiest solution is just recording it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354690351377-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium)

It might also be the case you will need to perform [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) of some dynamic parameters, at least [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) so your test should look like:

- Open login page
- Perform login

and make sure to add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)

And finally I don't think that you should pass credentials via query string because it's very insecure, normally you should use [HTTP POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) method for that and the credentials will go in the request body

Comment: I have tried the above mentioned items but issue remains same..  May be I am not able to handle the HTTP Cookie Manager, can you please explain more for cookies part